Inversion of center $A$; orthogonal circles/ Inversion about limiting point $A$

Let $C_1,C_2$ be two disjoint , nonconcentric circles with centers $O_1,O_2$. Consider $\mathit{D}$ to be the orthogonal circle to $C_1,C_2$ with center at a point of the line $O_1O_2$ and let $\overline{AB}$ be the diameter of $\mathit{D}$ over this same line.


Show that every inversion of center $A$ transform $C_1,C_2$ to concentric ones.

Given an orthogonal circle to $C_1,C_2$ as it passes through $A$, it transforms to a line passing through the intersection points between the inversive circle and the orthogonal one. Should I use the intersection points of this new line with $C_1$ and then apply the same process with $C_2$?
EDIT: We have that $C_{1},C_{2}$ are orthogonal to $O_{1}O_{2}$ and as $O_{1}O_{2}$ is left unchanged by the inversion of center $A$, so we must have that inverted $C_{1},C_{2}$ are also orthogonal to $O_{1}O_{2}$; furthermore, both $C_{1},C_{2}$ are orthogonal to $D$ whose inverse $D'$ is a line passing through the points $D \cap \mathcal{C}$; where $\mathcal{C}$ is the circle of inversion. The inverses of $C_{1},C_{2}$ are orthogonal to the line $D'$, but this implies that the center of these inverses is $D' \cap O_{1}O_{2}$, so they are concentric.
Moreover, the pencil of circles with limiting points $A,B$ is inverted to the pencil of concentric circles centered at the given point. Does this suffice as a justification? Any more thoughts

It might be easier to just calculate where the center of the inverted circles are, and show that they coincide.

This related question can be helpful.

See Lachlan, Modern Pure Geometry (1893) article 371, which refers back to article 356.  Older geometry textbooks like this have the proofs, and this one is accessible online.

@brainjam, how would the statement 'the inverse of the centre of a given circle is the inverse with respect to the inverse circle of the centre of inversion' apply to this situation?

Nice! Your proof works and is short and to the point.  Also, the inverse of $B$ in $\mathcal C$ is the center of the concentric circles.  Further, the set of circles orthogonal to $C_1,C_2$ (called the conjugate coaxal system) inverts to the set of lines passing through the center of the concentric circles.  Consider moving your proof to an answer, so that your question appears as answered.

'EDIT': We have that $C_{1},C_{2}$ are orthogonal to $O_{1}O_{2}$ and as $O_{1}O_{2}$ is left unchanged by the inversion of center $A$, so we must have that inverted $C_{1},C_{2}$ are also orthogonal to $O_{1}O_{2}$; furthermore, both $C_{1},C_{2}$ are orthogonal to $D$ whose inverse $D'$ is a line passing through the points $D \cap \mathcal{C}$; where $\mathcal{C}$ is the circle of inversion. The inverses of $C_{1},C_{2}$ are orthogonal to the line $D'$, but this implies that the center of these inverses is $D' \cap O_{1}O_{2}=B$, so they are concentric.
